# How I can get the first 3 digits in 123456 Numbers in sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have field called **CallingParty** in My CDR table it contains data like this:

```
CallingParty
------------
267672668788
```

I want to select the first 3 number of each of those numbers like

```
CallingParty
------------
267
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: how to get the left 3 numbers from an int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640048/sql-how-to-get-the-left-3-numbers-from-an-int)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: how to get the left 3 numbers from an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640048/sql-how-to-get-the-left-3-numbers-from-an-int)

Answer (score 14):

if `CallingParty` is of type int:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CallingParty, 3) AS INT)
From CDR
```

Comment: No need to `CAST` explicitly, `LEFT(123456,3)` will do an implicit cast anyway.

Comment: That wasn't the cast I meant! Your edit has broken your answer as now you have a dangling `AS INT` I meant the cast to `varchar` as input to the `LEFT` function. Some people might prefer the explicit cast anyway but I find it more readable/less noisy without.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a Left() function, but it works best on strings. (varchar/char in SQL)

```
Select left(cast(267672668788 as varchar), 3)
```

Comment: left is more readable, and less confusing especially when some systems start at 0 and some at 1. KISS

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CallingParty AS VARCHAR(50)), 1, 3) FROM [CDR]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data length does not change then you can always divide by 10 * the digits you have

```
SELECT FLOOR(267672668788 / 1000000000)
=267
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Substring(callingparty, 1, Length(callingparty) - 9) 
FROM   cdr;
```