# How to convert an integer field into a date in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

i have an integer field which has date values but i would like to convert it as date field.  I have tried several methods but with no success. The field has Date values but is stored as an Integer. This is what i have tried:

```
  cast(MYFIELD AS DATE) AS MYCOLUMN
```

but i get this error "Cannot cast type INT4 to DATE".
I have done several research but coul not find good solution for netezza.

Comment: what does your integer value for date look like ?

Comment: this is how it look like: 201004

Comment: how would one know how to convert that number to a date?  Is there some standard to be followed?

Comment: this data is being used in some other places so the data type has to be a date format in order to use for some other purpose

Comment: how do you translate "201004" into a date?  what's the YEAR, MONTH and DAY?  Once you have that, you can convert it into a date format that SQL will be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `01` and then run a `to_date`

```
select to_date(201004||'01','YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is something that you can do, not in an obvious way at least.  There are hundreds of ways a human could represent a date as an int, so the conversion would not be built in.an int would be something like 20120415 or 04152013 or hundreds of other formats and a date would be something like '2012-04-15'
I suggest you look at the top answer for [How i can get the first 3 digits in 123456 Numbers in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828804/how-i-can-get-the-first-3-digits-in-123456-numbers-in-sql) and extract your data manually. what you should do though, is convert the field into a real date field and edit the dependencies to expect that format.