# PHP substr - first parameter does not accept integers

Tags: php, integer, substring, substr

The PHP ***substr*** function does not accept strings converted from integers... :P

**The situation**

If I leave the code like this, it works:

```
<?php

$key = '35110100840754000150550010000014301000000809';
echo substr($key, 35, -1);

?>
```

And the result is right:

```
00000080
```

**The problem**

But I get this key from an integer variable (from the database). So the result is null and similar to what I get from this code:

```
<?php

$key = 35110100840754000150550010000014301000000809;
echo substr($key, 35, -1);

?>
```

And the result is a blank string.

I tried everything, like **(string)** casting, ***substr($key."", 35, -1)*** , and it does not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database is returning an integer value, then it's subject to the 32-bit (or 64-bit if you're on a 64-bit server) limitations. 35110100840754000150550010000014301000000809 way exceeds the max integer value for even a 64-bit server.
It may be converted to a float, in which case you'll be losing accuracy.

Get your database query to cast it as a string, and that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The number is too big to be an integer in php, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

In you case, `35110100840754000150550010000014301000000809`, will be something like `3.5110100840754E43` (give or take a few digits). As you start at position `35` (after the end of the string...), the result will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

try to print $key after substr. You'll see that the number is already null after the function.
The range of an integer is -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Apply a typecast in your value, converting to a string, strval() or (string)$key

Comment: Hi Gustavo! I tried casting (string)$key and strval($key) and it doesn't work... :P

Comment: But you are right in the range question! :) Thank you! E viva o Brasil!

Answer (score 0):

strval() might work. Check this related SO post, dealing with strings and mysql in PHP:
[Converting an integer to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-int-to-string-in-php)

Comment: Hi Girish! I tried casting (string)$key and strval($key) and it doesn't work... :P

Comment: Yup as Mr Baker states in your case the int is too large.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that the number is converted to a float when you assign it because it is overflowing the integer value.