# Adding some data to an array

Tags: php

ok here is some code

```
$highestRow = 16; // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = 'F'; // e.g 'F'

$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5


for ($row = 9; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
$val=array(); //i have initialized the array
  for ($col = 1; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
   $cell=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
   $val[]=$cell->getValue();

  }
echo $val[0] //from what is read from excel, it returns data like this 7563
}
```

How the data was in the excel sheet before, `B9` had `75`, `B10` had `6` and `B11` had `3`

After reading i `echo $val[0] //output 7563`

Now i would like to add additional data to the result so if i `echo $val[0]` after adding the info it shows the output as

```
echo $val[0] //output average=75% ; rsd = 6%; n=3% instead of just 7563
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but I'll give it a try. You have an array called $k. In that array you have a key[0], which contains "average = x; rsd = y; n=z" Do you want to add a new key or change a certain key in that array ?

Comment: Does "xyz" accurately represent the real data? Is it literally "xyz", Is it a string? a number? how is it formatted?

Comment: I have edited the question with some code, hope its clear now

Comment: Thanks for updating. That certainly sheds more light on the matter. I still don't understand why `getCellByColumnAndRow` reads 3 columns at a time. Granted I'm not familiar with PHPExcel, but the inner `for` loop reads each column in turn, so I would expect `$val[0]=75`, `$val[1]=6`, and `$val[2]=3` -- incrementing for each `$val[]=$cell->getValue();` What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you could try `echo $cell->getValue();` inside the inner `for` loop. I suspect there's a better way to organize your data with associative arrays, but I'm not understanding why the data is clumped together like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($k as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key."=".$value."; ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of array that you have you can either directly edit it as a string, or you have to turn it into a string.

If the value is already a string you can simply do string manipulation, you can create a temporary or use the original string and edit it all at once to be echoed, depends on what you prefer.

```
$strTemp = "output average=substr($var[0],0,2)% ; "rsd =substr($var[0]%,2,1); n=substr($var[0]%,3,1);" //can also use $var[0] instead of strTemp
```

If the values are in integer format you will have to turn the values into strings and then you can move on from there. If you don't know how, I advise this thread: [Converting an integer to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php)

Another thing, I'd advise storing the numbers in different parts of the array, that way its easier to reference them and tell them apart.