# need a workaroung to use '0' has a index in a php array and converting to json with json_encode()

Tags: php, arrays, json

Before you answer, I know that 0 returns null, false or a empty string, and thats the problem. What I want to know is if there is a workaround for that.

Im trying to convert a php array to json, but the json_encode() function is not preserving the index, my array is.

```
    Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 1
            [name] => Carteiras
            [parent] => 0
            [weight] => 0
          )
        [1] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 2
            [name] => Bolsas
            [parent] => 0
            [weight] => 1
          )
        [2] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 3
            [name] => Cintos
            [parent] => 0
            [weight] => 2
          )
        [3] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 4
            [name] => Chinelos
            [parent] => 0
            [weight] => 3
          )
        [4] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 5
            [name] => Tênis Masculino
            [parent] => 0
            [weight] => 4
          )
        [5] => Array
          (
            [idCategory] => 6
            [name] => Rasteiras
            [parent] => 1
            [weight] => 5
          )
       )
    )
```

The json:

```
{"Menu": [
  [
    {
      "idCategory": "1",
      "name": "Carteiras",
      "parent": "0",
      "weight": "0"
    },
    {
      "idCategory": "2",
      "name": "Bolsas",
      "parent": "0",
      "weight": "1"
    },
    {
      "idCategory": "3",
      "name": "Cintos",
      "parent": "0",
      "weight": "2"
    },
    {
      "idCategory": "4",
      "name": "Chinelos",
      "parent": "0",
      "weight": "3"
    },
    {
      "idCategory": "5",
      "name": null,
      "parent": "0",
      "weight": "4"
    },
    {
      "idCategory": "6",
      "name": "Rasteiras",
      "parent": "1",
      "weight": "5"
    }
  ]
]}
```

The first Array i setted using

```
    $i = 0;
    $array[$i] = $somearray;
```

The arrays containing idCategory, name, parent and weight I put inside the array using

```
    $somearray[] = $node;
```

everything works right if I use

```
    $array[$i . '_id'] = $somearray;
```

Comment: If you re-convert the json in object with `json_decode($json_string,true)` you got exactly the original array. So where is the problem?

Comment: I dont want to re-convert, I want to use the json in a javascript project.

Comment: but in javascript you can access to element with `jsonObject.Menu[2]` and you got object `Cintos`

Comment: The numbers are not sequential, I need the index, the problem is that I cant set 0 as a Index.

Answer (score 0):

JSON will only accept strings as keys. The easiest workaround would be to encapsulate your indexes with single quotes which would give the same effect as $i.'_id'.

```
   Array
(
  ['0'] => Array
  (
    ['0'] => Array
      (
        [idCategory] => 1
        [name] => Carteiras
        [parent] => 0
        [weight] => 0
      )
  )
)
```

If you'd like a variable to be converted you can use double quotes like `"$1"` or you could use the `strval()` function to convert your integers to strings.

Also see: [Using number as "index" (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json)
and: [Converting an integer to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried everything u said before asking here, nothing works with 0's.

Comment: Seems to me the strings are converted to integers as long as you have sequential indexes, without any breaks starting with zero. For example if you make an array like `array("0" => "zero, "1" => "one", "4" => "four")` the keys WILL be stored as strings. However if you do `array("0" => "zero, "1" => "one", "2" => "two")` and keep it sequential the keys will be converted to integers by php and json will ignore the keys. However if you'd convert it back the keys should be as they were original, because they are sequential. Perhaps this means there is no problem?

Comment: If php works as you said, then this probably will be no problem, if this is true too, I can just reverse the array to get the index. Thanks