# PHP strpos() function returning incorrect result

Tags: php

I am simply trying to see if a numeric year is contained inside a string of car years and models.  I would think the following code should show $my_str as FALSE.  But it return 9.  How?  The 9 position is a lower case "l".  Makes no sense to me unless the fact my needle is numeric screws things up.  But later I will create a loop and really want $my_needle to be numeric.

```
$my_haystack = "2007 Cadillac CTS";
$my_needle = 1900;
$my_str = strpos($my_haystack, $my_needle);
echo "my_str=$my_str"; //Returns my_str=9
```

Comment: And if you used `'1900'` instead of `1900` it would be correct - don't search for an integer value inside a string; search for a string inside a string

Comment: I think it's due to my_needle being an integer

Comment: [PHP Documentation 101](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - `If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the __ordinal value__ of a character.` `ordinal 1900` adjusts to `ordinal 49` after adjusting for byte range 0-255

Comment: Cast to string strpos($my_haystack, strval($my_needle)); That should allow you to keep it as an integer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't search for an INT inside a string using this function, you could convert the int to string before searching, like this:

```
$my_haystack = "2007 Cadillac CTS";
$my_needle = 1900;
$my_str = strpos($my_haystack, strval($my_needle));
```