# Convert big integer or float to string exactly as they are

Tags: php, yii2, floating-point, numbers

> pay attention the integer is bigger than PHP_INT_MAX (9223372036854775807)

Code:

```
  $x = 1502648031311810478;
  var_dump($x);
```

Output:

```
float 1.502648031381E+16
```

I want this:

```
1502648031311810478
```

as a string.

I tried all ways of casting but output is 1.502648031381E+16

I want exact integer in string.

This is not a duplicate of [Converting an integer to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php) because none of the answers to that question cover the case when the number is outside `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: Not reproducing: https://3v4l.org/oG43I

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya try it with another 0.  There seems to be a comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php#61292) without a solution.

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is not a Dupe. None of the answers in the duplicate marked link cover the case when the number is outside `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: @AlivetoDie agreed that OP's example is wrong. But his idea for asking this on right track. Please check the discussion above.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya question updated

Comment: Where exactly is the number coming from? The question cannot be answered properly without this information.

Comment: @SalmanA this is the number that i want to save to db to use somewhere else but i need exact number to use. something like it's pointer

Comment: @mohsen apparently you're using 32-bit PHP so it cannot represent this number as int, it will be auto-converted to float. You can specify the number as string though `$x = '1502648031311810478';` which is why I asked where it comes from.

Comment: @SalmanA i use 64bit php and number come from some web service that use this long number as pointer to other methods and i just want to save it and use it in future.

Comment: @mohsen is it coming as json (and you're running json_decode on it)? And are you sure about PHP being 64 bit (check `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` and post what it returns)

Comment: @SalmanA exaclty coming from json and running json_decode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183489/discussion-between-salman-a-and-mohsen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). It will convert numbers to integers where possible, otherwise float:

```
// 32bit integers
var_dump(json_decode("2147483647")); // int(2147483647)
var_dump(json_decode("2147483648")); // float(2147483648)

// 64bit integers
var_dump(json_decode("9223372036854775807")); // int(9223372036854775807)
var_dump(json_decode("9223372036854775808")); // float(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

You can use `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` flag so that `json_decode` *decodes large integers as their original string value*:

```
// 32bit integers
var_dump(json_decode("2147483647", false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)); // int(2147483647)
var_dump(json_decode("2147483648", false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)); // string(10) "2147483648"
// 64bit integers
var_dump(json_decode("9223372036854775807", false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)); // int(9223372036854775807)
var_dump(json_decode("9223372036854775808", false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)); // string(19) "9223372036854775808"
```

Note that the number-as-a-string is not really useful for arithmetic e.g. you cannot add or multiply from it without it (auto) converting to float.