# How to fix error of "Array (...) does not match expected type "NULL"."?

Tags: php, arrays

While working on a kata for Codewars, I am coming across an error when printing a value. Although the output of the code looks fine, I am getting the error that `Array (...) does not match expected type "NULL".`

Any ideas what I can change in my code to return a string?

```php
function reverseSeq ($n) {
  $n = range($n, 1);
  foreach($n as $i) {
    if ($i > 1) {
      print_r ($i.",");
      $i--;
    } else {
      print_r ($i);
    }
  }
}
```

The output, when `$n` is 3, prints 3,2,1 as it should. However, it should return as a string rather than an integer.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all, but remove `$i--;`.

Comment: I get a feeling that you are looking for `implode(', ', range($n, 1));`, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Do you want to convert your integer to a String? Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035634/4118280) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Codewars katas, you need to `return` the value to the testing function, which will then validate it. Printing to stdout is helpful for debugging, but has no bearing on the test's pass/failure outcome. `Array (...) does not match expected type "NULL".` is a generic PHPUnit failed assertion message that happens to not be especially helpful: it doesn't show the contents of the expected array or log the actual and expected values in the correct order. The author of the kata reversed the arguments to `$this->assertEquals(reverseSeq(5), [5,4,3,2,1]);`, so `Array (...)` is the value the test suite expects and `NULL` is what your function returns).

Try simply:

```
function reverseSeq($n) {
    return range($n, 1);
}
```

Outcome from the test runner:

```
You have passed all of the tests! :)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm a new coder as I am switching from network administration to programming. It seems I was overthinking this problem.

Comment: No problem. Codewars is a great way to get started with some fun exercises once you get the hang of it.