# Paginated PHP web scraper

Tags: php, loops, url

Hi there I'm new here.

Trying to make this little code to loop over pages. And scrape off links of headings .

Scraping part works just fine but i cant make it to loop to the next page. It keeps looping on the same page.

```
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// start at page 1
$xder = 1;
do {

// web page + page number (should change with every loop)

$html = file_get_html('https://webpage.com/stuff/page/$xder');

foreach($html->find('h3') as $h3) 
{
       foreach($h3->find('a') as $element) 
       {
            echo $element->href . '<br>';
      }
}

    $xder++;

} while ($xder <= 5);
?>
```

I'm expecting to get list of links from all 5 pages, but I only get list of links from 1st page repeating 5 times.

I think the problem is here "/stuff/page/$xder');" I'm not sure how to add a variable to the back of an URL it doesn't appear to work.

Tried methods here:

[Converting an integer to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php)

Getting frustrated with this. Not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks for any thoughts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php variables are treated as variables only if you use `"`, and not `'`

Change

```
$html = file_get_html('https://webpage.com/stuff/page/$xder');
```

to

```
$html = file_get_html("https://webpage.com/stuff/page/{$xder}");
```