# giving array values with double quotes PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, explode

i have this json array code in php

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-6.893238,107.604273&radius=100&type=point_of_interest&keyword=oleh-oleh&key=mykey";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data);

$i = 0;
$results = array_map(function($result) use (&$i) {
    return array ("id" => ++$i , "longitude" => $result->geometry->location->lng, "latitude" => $result->geometry->location->lat, "description" => $result->vicinity, "name" => $result->name);
}, $json->results);

$results = explode('","', $results);

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Which gives me array values like this :

`[{"id":18,"longitude":107.6123014,"latitude":-6.897495399999999,"name":"Kaos Oleh Oleh Khas Bandung & Kaos Otomotif"}]`

How can I add double quotes on lat and long like this :

`[{"id":18,"longitude":"107.6123014","latitude":"-6.897495399999999","name":"Kaos Oleh Oleh Khas Bandung & Kaos Otomotif"}]`

i tried explode with this code

`$results = explode('","', $results);`

but it gives me warning : warning explode() expects parameter 2

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why do you need quotes?

Comment: _Cast_ the values to the string data type, in the very place where you are adding them to that array to begin with.

Comment: @u_mulder it's required by the tools im working on right now

Comment: I don't think you really need cast to string, your tools will work fine with numeric values.

Comment: @u_mulder i tried running the program, sadly it doesn't show the data

Comment: @CBroe sorry but how can i do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035634/converting-an-integer-to-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast to string

```
$results = array_map(function($result) use (&$i) {
    return array (
               "id" => ++$i , 
               "longitude" => (string) $result->geometry->location->lng, 
               "latitude" => (string) $result->geometry->location->lat,
               "description" => $result->vicinity, 
               "name" => $result->name
               );
}, $json->results);
```

Comment: or you can concatenate the Quote with `'"'+value+'"'`